# Incentive Distribution Based on Percentage

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula

This is an example of incentive distribution that is calculated based on performance score given by the Head and the manager.

[image]

There is total comes to more than allocated monthly incentive, please help to solve this issue

Sheet Link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fqDrI1I1adihebF_TYNY5HtqyBz8KthiI1SrKhQp1KY/edit#gid=0

Comment: CEO's score and Manager's score don't sum up 100%

Comment: They are scoring scoring out of 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=$B$7*D2/sum($D$2:$D$5)
```

[image]